# Passing multiple arguments to function in dplyr::summarise_if

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to make a function that uses summarise_if (or summarise_at) to calculate the correlation between one column and many others in the data set.

```
data_set <- data.frame(grp = rep(c("a","b","c"), each = 
3), x = rnorm(9), y = rnorm(9), z = rnorm(9))

multiple_cor <- function(d, vars){
 d %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(grp) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_at(vars, cor, x) %>% 
  return()
}

multiple_cor(data_set, vars = c("y","z") )
```

This gives the error:

```
Error in dots_list(...) : object 'x' not found
Called from: dots_list(...)
```

I'm am fairly sure this is from the `cor` function not evaluating `x` within the right environment, but I am not sure how to get around this issue.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773881/r-object-not-found-if-defined-within-a-function-when-using-data-table-dplyr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R object not found if defined within a function when using data.table dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773881/r-object-not-found-if-defined-within-a-function-when-using-data-table-dplyr)

Answer (score 3):

`summarise_at` has a funs argument so it can handle anonymous functions. I created a function called cors inside your function and pass that one on to `summarise_at` inside the funs argument to handle the x.

```
multiple_cor <- function(d, vars){
  cors <- function(x, a = NULL) {
    stats::cor(x, a)
  }
  d %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(grp) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise_at(vars, funs(cors(x, .))) %>% 
    return()
}

multiple_cor(data_set, vars = c("y","z") )

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  grp        y      z
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a      0.803  0.894
2 b     -0.284 -0.949
3 c      0.805 -0.571
```

The outcome of the function is exactly identical as the following lines of code:

```
data_set %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(cxy = cor(x, y),
            cxz = cor(x, z))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  grp      cxy    cxz
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a      0.803  0.894
2 b     -0.284 -0.949
3 c      0.805 -0.571
```

Read [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) dplyr documentation.

And [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/_C3x4kvXo-A) google groups discussion.